# Selecting 'Merge Files' for 'Copy Behavior' distorting file name in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory and am encountering a problem where in the 'Sink' section of my ADF pipeline, if I specify 'Merge Files' as the 'Copy Behavior', my output file name is getting distorted. What would have otherwise taken the same name as my input file, the output file name is now taking a name like 'data_followed_by_some_random_space_separated_number'. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is expected behavior. If you want to copy a single file, specify the path to the file instead of the folder when the data source selects the path. And specified as None when choosing the copy behavior.

Comment: If my answer answers your doubts, can you mark it as the answer to end this question? Thanks. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu certainly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. You need to know the meaning of this operation, it can copy multiple files into one file. If you want to specify its name, you should specify the final name when setting the copy behavior. I found that you mentioned the word "distortion", so I think what you really want to do is actually copy the corresponding file, then you should not choose the copy behavior (that is, specify the copy behavior as "None")